# Is this line delivered by Arsenio Hall an homage to a film, made 12 year prior?

Tags: reference

Below are excerpts of these two screenplays.  The delivery of the lines suggests that John Landis and crew (of *Amazon...*) may have been paying homage to the Philip Marlowe noir detective drama of a movie made 12 years earlier.

Though the names are not exact, I'd assumed that they preferred Thelma since Velma was an antiquated name by the late 80's.

Considering the following, would Landis have been paying homage to this older film?

From the [*Farewell, My Lovely* screenplay](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=farewell-my-lovely):

> *Marlowe*: I'm looking for Velma. 
>  
>   *Pool Hall Antagonist*: Velma, you says? No Velma here.

Compare that to Arsenio Hall's character ("Apartment Victim") his *Amazon Women of the Moon* sketch: *Mondo Condo*  (from the [screenplay](https://www.scripts.com/script/amazon_women_on_the_moon_2643)).  Arsenio is fielding phone calls from someone we can't hear: (my own explanation of the scene in **bold**)

> **(first phone call, calm delivery)** No. You got the wrong number. Yeah,
>   but ain't no Thelma here, man. 
> ...
>  **(called back, tenant is now
>   agitated)** What? Man, there ain't no Thelma here! 
> ...
>  **(called
>   again, tenant is literally putting out fires)** What? Ain't no f@kin'
>   Thelma here, man! Look, the bitch don't live here! F@k you too!

Comment: I really don't see any connection. The phrases aren't even the same, and the phrases are fairly common anyway.

Comment: I don't have a definitive answer but it's entirely possible given that the whole movie is an homage to the sorts of movies you'd see on late night TV in the late '70s/early '80s (and "Farewell" was definitely in that category). If I find a solid answer, I'll post it.